# Nginx and a symlinked root directory inside a Dropbox folder cause a "File not found."

Tags: nginx, dropbox, php

**Original question**

> I met a strange problem with nginx + php-fpm.
>
> If my root directory set to something like
>   `~/playground/apps/foo/public/`, everything works fine.
>
> If I symlink `~/playground` to `~/Dropbox/playground` Nginx renders a
>   **"File not found."** string.
>
> I first thought that it was a permissions problem, but it isn't
>   (double checked with a simple php file)
>
> So my question is: Is a symlinked root direcotry a problem for nginx
>   and php-fpm?

**Update**
This is definitely caused by Dropbox.
I did the same symlink dance and evrything works fine.
But symlinking a root directory inside a Dropbox folder breaks something. (suspecting permissions but don't see any change)

Any hint ?

Comment: Could you post your nginx configuration and your Dropbox permissions/tree?

Comment: Just found that it was caused by a permission problem of the default Dropbox folder. Solved!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was sure that it was something very stupid.

The default Dropbox folder permissions are too restrictive.
A `chmod 755 ~/Dropbox` solved it.

Sorry for your time, and thanks again.